# QGIS - Retrieve start and end features from a line

Tags: line, qgis

I'm creating lines by selecting two features from various layers. When I create a line a form pops up. In this form I want to display data from the start and end features of the line.
What I'm currently doing is retrieving the vertices as point :

```
geom = feature.geometry ()
line = geom.asPolyline ()
pointFather = ligne[0]
pointChild = ligne[-1]
```

then I get the coordinates of each point :

```
xf = pointFather.x()
yf = pointFather.y()
```

and then I look into each possible layer to find the features with the same coordinates, just to retrieve the features I just clicked on !

```
for layer in layerList:
    provider = layer.dataProvider()
    iter = provider.getFeatures()
    for feature in iter:
        geom = feature.geometry().asPoint()
        if geom.x() == xf and geom.y() == yf:
```

It must be something easier to do to directly retrieve the start and end features, isn't it ?

**EDIT 1 :**

here is my try after PCamargo first answer :

```
def retrieve_feature_from_xy(geom,point,layerList):
  for layer in layerList:
    index = QgsSpatialIndex()
    iter = layer.getFeatures()
    for feat in iter:
        index.insertFeature(feat)
    ids = index.intersects(geom.boundingBox())
    request = QgsFeatureRequest()
    request.setFilterFids(ids)
    iter = layer.getFeatures(request)
    for feat in iter:
        geom2 = feat.geometry().asPoint()
        if geom2.x() == point.x() and geom2.y() == point.y():
            return feat
```

**EDIT 2 :**

Here is my try after PCamargo second comment :

```
def retrieve_feature_from_xy2(geom,point,layerList):
    allfeatures = {}
    indexes=[]
    ids=[]
    for layer in layerList:
        index = QgsSpatialIndex()
        iter = layer.getFeatures()
        for feat in iter:
            index.insertFeature(feat)
            allfeatures[feat.id()]=feat
        indexes.append(index)
    for index in indexes:
        intersect_ids = index.intersects(geom.boundingBox())
        ids.append(intersect_ids)
    for id in ids:
        for i in id:
            feat=allfeatures[i]
            geom2=feat.geometry().asPoint()
            if geom2.x() == point.x() and geom2.y() == point.y():
                return feat
```

**EDIT 3**

Here is my try after PCamargo third comment :

```
def retrieve_feature_from_xy3(geom,point,layerList):    
    allfeatures = {}
    indexes=[]
    ids=[]
    indexDict = {}
    intersectsIdsDict = {}

    for layer in layerList:
        index = QgsSpatialIndex()
        iter = layer.getFeatures()
        for feat in iter:
            index.insertFeature(feat)
            allfeatures[layer,feat.id()]=feat
        indexes.append(index)
        indexDict[layer]=index

    for layer, index in indexDict.items():
        intersectsIds = index.intersects(geom.boundingBox())
        intersectsIdsDict[layer]=intersectsIds      

    for layer, index in intersectsIdsDict.items():
        for id in index:
            feat = allfeatures[layer,id]    
            geom2=feat.geometry().asPoint()
            if geom2.x() == point.x() and geom2.y() == point.y():
                return feat
```

Answer (score 2):

Chris,

You can definitely improve the look for similar coordinates (Third part of the code).

Instead of looping through all features in each layer, create a spatial index (https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#using-spatial-index) for each link and use nearestNeighbor.

It would be something like this:

```
#You only need to create these indices once
indexes=[]
for layer in layerlist:
    index = QgsSpatialIndex()
    for feat in layer:
        index.insertFeature(feat)

    indexes.append(index)
```

Now that we have the indexes, we can use faster geographic search.

```
geom = feature.geometry ()

for index in indexes:
    intersect_ids = index.intersects(geom.boundingBox())
```

***intersect_ids*** is a smaller list of features that are candidates to be equivalent, so you can compare only these features with the feature you selected.

You need to organize this a bit more, but that is the idea

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. You can see my try in the edit 1. I'm not sure that is exactly what you had in mind. The index creation is taking 1 sec for less that 20 features in all the layers. What could explain such a long time ?

Comment: @ChrisF, You should create the index only once, before you start your matching process, and use the indexes in each search. That would probably great increase the speed of your search.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I've tried what you've proposed in EDIT 2. But the function doesn't return the correct feature. I think that's because I'm looking into various layers and ids are only unique within a layer. So in the final last loop when I doing allfeature[i] it may not look in the correct layer. In fact when I put the "correct" layer (the one containing the feature I'm looking for) at the end of the layerList then it returns the correct feature. How could I fix that ?

Comment: @ChrisF, in fact it only returns the ID within that search layer, but you can get this ID and get it's associate features to bring back to your target layer. Does it make sense?

Comment: Thanks. It does make sense but how do you retrieve the layer of a given feature ?

Comment: I've tried something (see edit 3) using dictionaries. It works but I don't know if it's the more efficient. Were you thinking of something else ?

Comment: @ChrisF  you are still creating the indexes everytime you look for a point, which is very inneficient.  Try a something like  "def retrieve_feature_from_xy3(geom,point,spatial_indexes_dicctionary):". Instead of creating the dictionaries when you enter the function, you create before you even start trying to match points. And, what you will return from this function is the layer name/index and the feature index. With these two informations you can retrieve the feature itself and all its attributes.